# WebStorm SASS File Watcher on Windows

Tags: css, windows, sass, webstorm

*Unless .NET programming on Windows can be so much pita. God damnit*

**TL;DR** How do I get a SASS/SCSS processor working with WebStorm on Windows?

I want to set up a file watcher within WebStorm 9 to compile my css files.

Okay. Using the default setup for SASS/SCSS within the FileWatcher I get the following output.

```
cmd.exe /D /C C:/Ruby21/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update spinner.scss:spinner.css
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/Ruby21/bin/scss
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Ruby21/bin/scss
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find sass (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.8.0, minitest-2.5.1, rake-10.0.4, rdoc-3.12.2] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from C:/Ruby21/bin/scss:22:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Okay fine! Let's update the Working Directory to a cygwin path like this

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/foo/Documents/dev/...
```

Amazing. WebStorm is "fixing" the path to `c:\cygdrive\c\Users\...` and obviously let the process fail.

[image]

Comment: I can suggest disabling this sygwin warning - http://auxmem.com/2010/03/17/how-to-squelch-the-cygwin-dos-path-warning/

Comment: BTW, did you install ruby via cygwin? Does SASS work outside of WebStorm?

Comment: disabling won't help since the process would still fail, right? @lena I did install ruby via windows installer. SASS works very fine outside of webstorm

Comment: it's really strange. do you mean that running 'C:/Ruby21/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update spinner.scss:spinner.css' in windows cmd console works fine for you?

Comment: unbelievable:) Please attach a screenshot of cmd.exe console with the command and output